# Position matrix and distance from each position

Tags: matlab

I have created a position matrix which I am happy with, and for each position (or element) of this matrix, I want to calculate the positional distance between all other positions in the matrix. This way i can obtain the direction each other element is from another. I have tried to do this in the following way:

```
pos = [X(:),Y(:),Z(:)];

for j = 1:length(pos)
for i = 1:length(pos)
    vecdir(i,:,:) = pos(i,:,:) - pos(j,:,:);
end
    v(i) = {vecdir};
    i = i+1;
end
```

where each cell holds the positional distance per position in the position matrix. v(i) only seems to store the last calculation (i.e. all cells are empty apart from the last cell which holds the correct information for the last position on the position matrix.). Where am I going wrong here? Also, if there is a more efficient way of doing this then I'd like to know, as I know storing and accessing cell arrays slows programs down a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're is always [pdist2](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/stats/pdist2.html):

```
dist = pdist2(pos,pos);
```

which gives the norm of the distance vectors.

In case you also need the distance vectors I'd use something like this:

```
N = size(pos,1);
v = arrayfun(@(ii) bsxfun(@minus,pos,pos(ii,:)),1:N,'uni',false)
```

which returns a `Nx1` cell array, each cell containing the distance vector of `pos(ii,:)` to the other positions.

Your code seems to do the same, altough there are some errors; I think you intended to do the following:

```
N = size(pos,1);
v = cell(N,1);
for j = 1:N
    for i = 1:N
        vecdir(i,:) = pos(i,:) - pos(j,:);
    end
    v{j} = vecdir;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What are these statements doing at the end of your loop over `j` ?

```
v(i) = {vecdir};
i = i+1;
```

As I read your code, these always set `v(length(pos))` to `{vecdir}` and then add `1` to `i`. This updated value of `i` is never used before it is reset (to `1`) at the next go round the inner loop.

I can't say that the rest of your code is OK, I'm not sure I follow your question entirely, but these bits smell a bit fishy.

Comment: Yes I see how i = i+1 was deleting previous storage. thanks mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = repmat(X(:), 1, numel(X));
y = repmat(Y(:), 1, numel(Y));
z = repmat(Z(:), 1, numel(Z));

dst = sqrt((x - x') .^ 2 + (y - y') .^ 2 + (z - z') .^ 2);
```